# SEO: lightbox images invisible to search engines

Tags: html, ajax, seo, lightbox, google-image-search

We have a website where the majority of the images are loaded on lightboxes via Ajax loading (so not initially loaded, but by clicking to open lightbox), so search engines can't index these images when crawling this page. Is there any way to improve SEO for these lightbox images?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When a user clicks to open the light box you need to provide an alternate for Googlebot.  I'm going to assume that you have an image thumbnail in the page that the user clicks on.  On the thumbnail, you have a click event that causes the AJAX to bring up the lightbox.

You also need to link the thumbnail directly to the large version of the same image that the lightbox would show.  This is the alternate for clients without Javascript.  The onclick event that opens the lightbox then needs to `return false` so that users with javascript don't open the link *too*.  Here is the code for it:

```
<a onclick="lightbox('my-picture');return false;" href="/fullpics/my-picture.jpg">
    <img src="/thumbnails/my-picture.jpg" border=0>
</a>
```

It turns out that Googlebot doesn't care for image search whether your image is shown in the page, or linked from the page.  So to Googlebot, for image optimization purposes, the above is the same as `<img src="/fullpics/my-picture.jpg">`, but it takes up much less visible space in your page, and is more similar to the way that your site currently is designed.

You should also put your thumbails into `robots.txt` so that Google doesn't try to index those instead:

```
Disallow: /thumbnails/
```

The bigger that you make your fullsized images, the better they will rank.   Google says that it prefers better quality images.  As far as I can tell "better quality" is just a euphemism for "bigger".   I'd recommend at least 800px in the larger direction.

Comment: I feel I should point out that although a perfectly valid example, returning `false` from event handlers is an icky practise, possibly breaking things elsewhere on a page.

Comment: thanks Stephen and akaIDIOT! I will give it a try

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on the subject, but my approach to this is to always have the 'link' that opens the lightbox with the image actually link to the image. As the lightbox is presumably opened with JavaScript, cancel the default action of pointing the browser to the image and open a lightbox instead. Needless to say: a search engine will be able to find your image as you explicitly link to it. As an added bonus: this also works for users that have JavaScript turned off (they won't have to deal with a link that does nothing).